# Programmatically send text message through Messages app on OS X 10.10

Tags: messages, sms

With OSX 10.10 you can now send and receive text messages through your phone, from your mac. Is it possible to do this programatically? Either via applescript or a reverse engineered API?

Answer (score 13):

Using:

```
tell application "Messages"
    get name of every service
end tell
```

I noticed that I have "SMS" as a 4th option (yours may be different). So then I used:

```
launch application "Messages"
tell application "Messages"
     activate --steal focus

     set targetBuddy to "12345550123"
     set targetService to id of service "SMS"
     set textMessage to "Just a test"

     set theBuddy to buddy targetBuddy of service id targetService
     send textMessage to theBuddy
end tell
```

This lets me send a text message over SMS Relay. I'm not 100% sure that I did this correctly, but it does work if targetService points to "SMS". Now to convert it to script that works from the terminal.

Answer (score 10):

There is quite a few good examples out there for using Applesccript to send iMessages.  I haven't found one yet that will work to a number via sms, the below script only works with iMessage.  Also it limited to the number(s) in your contacts(buddy list) and will error out if the buddy/number isn't in your contacts.  Here's one that I use to send notifications of a server backup complete.

Create an applescript named "*sendMessage.scpt*" with the following code:

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
tell application "Messages"
    set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set targetBuddy to buddy targetBuddyPhone of targetService
    send targetMessage to targetBuddy
end tell
end run
```

Then from **terminal.app** run this command to send iMessage:

```
osascript /path/to/sendMessage.scpt 12345550123 "Your Text Message to Send"
```

just change *12345550123* to the number your sending to.

[Link to original guide from stackeoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812184/how-to-send-an-imessage-text-with-applescript-only-in-provided-service)

Comment: To start a new conversation, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451691/317461

Answer (score 6):

**send.scpt**

```
on run {phoneNumber, message}
    tell application "Messages"
    send message to buddy phoneNumber of service "SMS"
    end tell
end run
```

**run from terminal like this:**

`osascript send.scpt +48500123456 'hello andi!'`

this works both with iMessage and standard SMS when you have enabled on your iPhone the option `Text Message Forwarding` by setting your e.g macbook device.